# Command 'setenv' not found upon installation of Crystal09 program

Tags: 11.04

**Command 'setenv' not found**

I use ubuntu 11.04

I tried to install the program "Crystal09" and in the tutorial asks you to copy the file cry2k9.cshrc
to the home directory. I copied the file, but when I do the command "source cry2k9.cshrc" (which is the installation tutorial)
the following error appears **(This error message is in Portuguese-br)**:
(Translated :edit)

```
Command 'setenv' not found, did you mean:

Command 'netenv' package 'netenv' (universe)

setenv: command not found

Command 'setenv' not found, did you mean:

Command 'netenv' package 'netenv' (universe)

setenv: command not found

CRY2K9_SCRDIR - scratch directory (integrals and temp files):

CRY2K9_EXEDIR - directory with crystal executables:

CRY2K9_UTILS - running scripts and misc: /runcry09, runprop09

CRY2K6_GRA - graphical scripts: /maps06, doss06, band06

CRY2K9_TEST - directory with test cases:
```

Comment: Do you run the command 'source cry2k9.cshrc' from the home directory. If not ,use cd command to go there and try again. Also if you post the link of tutorial , it will be helpful.

Comment: http://www.crystal.unito.it/Manuals/howtoinstall.txt

Answer (score 2):

Those are C-shell commands, and Ubuntu by default uses bash as the shell. You need to install the C shell and run it. Do:

```
    sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

and enter your password. Once done, simply run `tcsh` and go through the tutorial. Type `exit` to go back from csh to bash.

You can convert the commands in the tutorial to bash, of course. `setenv` is equivalent to `export` (it has different syntax, though). This is what I would do, but if you are not familiar with different shells the above solution is a better option.

Comment: Well, the command "sudo apt-get install tcsh" I had tried and failed
I tried changing the setenv command to export the script as you said, and now is giving the following error (this error message is in Portuguese-br):

Comment: bash: export: `/home/cry98/CRYSTAL09': não é um identificador válido                                                            

bash: export: `Linux-ifort': não é um identificador válido
                                                      
bash: export: `/home/marcos': não é um identificador válido

bash: export: `//': não é um identificador válido

bash: export: `/utils09': não é um identificador válido

bash: export: `/crgra2006': não é um identificador válido

bash: export: `/test_cases/inputs': não é um identificador válido

bash: export: `/bin/Linux-pgf': não é um identificador válido

Comment: Follow the link to the tutorial:
http://www.crystal.unito.it/Manuals/howtoinstall.txt

Comment: In the tutorial it says: "3. From now on, the example is for C shell. If bash is your default shell please refer to cry2k9.bashrc file". Use that file instead by putting `source cry2k9.bashrc` in your `~/.bashrc` file. The syntax for bash's `export` is `export variable=value`, you are probably missing the equal sign. As for the installation of `tcsh`, what error did it give?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply use the equivalent bash command which is:

```
export ENV_VARIABLE=value
```

For example:

```
export LANG=en_US
```